# Upload video file with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have problem for upload video file with codeigniter 3. We use Linux Server Ubuntu 15.04. This is script controller for upload:

```
$config['upload_path']      = './uploads/videos/';
$config['allowed_types']    = 'mp4';
$config['max_size']         = 0;
$config['overwrite']        = FALSE;
$config['remove_spaces']    = TRUE;
```

and configuration php.ini:

```
post_max_size = 20000M
upload_max_filesize = 20000M
```

but we still error message:

> The uploaded file exceeds the maximum allowed size in your PHP configuration file

Comment: You don't want to tell us the size of the file you upload?

Comment: hii @DanielAlder size file upload is 500MB, this problem is solved. after we a config file php.ini in directory /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Comment: then why did you accept the answer below?

Comment: @DanielAlder we greatly appreciate an  given answer

Comment: But the accepted answer was modifying mimes.php which obviously didn't solve the problem. The correct way would be publishing an own answer about php.ini and what you *really* changed in it and then accepting that answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one
Inside the config/mimes.php add the missing file type you are going to uplaod, something like bellow.

```
    'mpeg'  =>  array('video/mpeg', 'video/quicktime'),
    'mpg'   =>  array('video/mpeg', 'video/quicktime'),
    'mp4'   =>  array('video/mp4', 'video/quicktime'),
    'mpe'   =>  array('video/mpeg', 'video/quicktime'),
    'qt'    =>  'video/quicktime',
    'mov'   =>  array('video/quicktime', 'video/mp4'),
    'avi'   =>  array('video/avi', 'video/x-msvideo'),
```

Comment: Hii @Rax Shah,, i still message "The uploaded file exceeds the maximum allowed size in your PHP configuration file"

Comment: Check for the post and upload file sizes first

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M`

Comment: i am change configuration php.ini for post_max_size = 20000M and upload_max_filesize = 20000M

Comment: Hii @Rax Shah problem is solved,, :D i am wrong change php.ini